# How do I make a google spreadsheet formula that ignores conditional formatting for odd cells that have been filled with a paint bucket?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

The only formula i've found that fills odd rows is

`=mod(row(),2)=0`

but I don't know how to somehow unite this formula with the other boolean for if cells are not filled.

Answer (score 2):

`AND` works fine with conditions. Also try `ISODD` instead `MOD`

```
=AND($E1="Female", ISODD(ROW($E1)))
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfect when there's a specific word but is there a formula for just filled boxes?

Comment: @AndyPhu what are boxes? Please specify this in your question.

Comment: Cells are what they’re officially known as, I’ve been told. 
An example of them could be A1, B3 and so on.

Comment: @AndyPhu `=AND($E1<>"", ISODD(ROW($E1)))` should be fine.